# Does this bathroom underslab plumbing plan meet code?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

Does this layout look like it would pass inspection in a basement under slab?

3" from sink to sewage pump to act as a "wet vent".

3" to toilet.

2" to shower with a 2"

The pipe heading off the page on the right goes to a sink 50' away that would have its own vent.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks

- Updated Picture
  [image]

Comment: Inspection by _whom_? Please revise to tell us where you are.

Comment: Of critical importance are the fitting types, slope, etc. It's hard to say anything with confidence from such a rough drawing.

Comment: I'm in Indiana. I understand fitting types and slope and such, just curious on if the basic layout would be okay. Mainly venting the toilet through a wet vent from the lavatory with a 3".. I believe it's overkill on code but not sure, so just curious on if it looks legal..... I'm trying to keep all the vents in one wall is the main issue....

Comment: Please put all information in your question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don’t need a separate vent for the shower as it can be included as part of the wet vent with the toilet, provided that these two fixtures are connected with a symmetrical fitting (double wye). Then, as long as the length of the shower drain does not require the grade on that section to fall more than the diameter of the pipe, it should be covered by the wet vent. Connect the drain from the faraway sink downstream of the symmetrical fitting, so it is not part of the wet vent.

The size of the wet vent would depend on your local code and how they determine the fixture units to be included in the sizing of the wet vent. Where I live, 2” would be fine for this setup, but there is nothing wrong with running it as 3”.

So fitting arraignment starting from the sewage pit:

1. 3" x 2" wye (or 3" x 2" combination wye) to pickup the faraway sink
2. 3" double wye (or 3" double combination wye)
3. 3” x 2” bushing in the left inlet of 3" double wye to pick up the shower
4. 3” pipe heading to the vanities in the centre inlet of the 3" double wye
5. 3” pipe and required bends heading the toilet from the right inlet of the 3" double wye

Comment: I think I see most saying the shower has to be within 5ft of a vent.. so maybe if I curve the 3" over towards the shower on it's way to the sink so the 2" shower is only 5ft would be better? I updated my picture

Comment: If you run a 2” pipe to the shower at 2%, the maximum length of the pipe from the wye to the shower is 8 feet. If you’re using a 1-1/2” pipe, it’s 6 feet. (The fall on the pipe cannot exceed the diameter of the pipe.) Your revised sketch looks fine.

Comment: I updated my photo again.. forgot the toilet flange would be parallel with the basin since 12" offset. One more question.. From what I've been told/always done... anything over 2.5" PVC can be 1/8" slope correct? My local plumber said that's fine, but I see this debated online so just figured I'd ask here quick.. Thanks

Comment: The required slope will depend on local codes. Where I live, 3” and smaller is to be sloped 1/4” per foot. However, the International Plumbing Code has the slope for 2-1/2" or less at 1/4, 3" to 6" at 1/8, and 8" or larger at 1/16 (table 704.1, 2018 edition).

Answer (score 0):

You need a breather vent for the shower and the sinks, or you will be sucking air back through the drains from your sewer.